# How to create statefulset with nodeAffinity

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

I'm trying to create a statefulset in kubernetes 1.9 with nodeAffinity.  I found some examples with a simple nodeselector, but that is not really what I would like to accomplish.  I want to make sure that statefulset instances always start on the same node, like this:

- statefulpod-0 on node-0
- statefulpod-1 on node-1
- statefulpod-2 on node-2

I tried labelling the corresponding nodes with the statefulpod-name, and using downward api in nodeselector or nodeaffinity, but I cannot produce a working yaml to do this.

The example:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - nodeSelectorTerms:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: statefulpodname
          operator: In
          values:
          - valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
```

The error:

> ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec.template.spec.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution):
>   invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.NodeSelector: got "map", expected
>   "array";

The example:

```
nodeSelector:
  statefulpodname:
  - valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
```

The error:

> invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.nodeSelector: got "array",
>   expected "string"

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like your validation errors don't really match your provided yaml snippets. Are you sure you provided up-to-date ones?

Comment: The above snippets are off course only a small part of the actual statefulset yaml, but the validation errors match the provided snippets afaik

Comment: Hi, did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

as error states `got "map", expected "array";`, try with :

```
- nodeSelectorTerms:
  - matchExpressions:
...
```

Comment: I tried but this results in the same error.  I guess downward API can only be used in env and volumes?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the YAML needs to be as follows;

```
spec: 
 affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: <key>
              operator: <operator>
              values:
              - <values>
```

Notice the placement of dash (-) characters.